# SQL oracle How can i multiply two columns from different tables and put the resulting column in one of the two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently working on an SQL project and my code just won't work this is what I tried

```
UPDATE detail_order 
    SET total = (
        SELECT (detail_order.quantity*product.PRICE_EXCLVAT) 
        FROM detail_order,product 
        where detail_order.npro=product.npro
    );
```

But oracle keeps telling me: ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row. But I can't figure out how to solve this because each product has one price and each order is linked to only one product so no confusion there. Some products are ordered several times but I can't see how this could be a problem.

Comment: HI.  please edit the question and show the table definitions and example data.  thanks

Comment: The best solution is to not store 'total' at all, if it can always be calculated at run time.  If 'price' can vary by date,  and you need to preserve the 'total' using the price of a given date, then you need to account for that.  Either way, your data model is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should probably be something like this:

```
update detail_order d set
  d.total = (select d.quantity * p.price_exclvat
             from product p
             where p.npro = d.npro
            )
where exists (select null from product a
              where a.npro = d.npro
             );
```

Or

```
merge into detail_order d
  using product p
  on (p.npro = d.npro)
  when matched then update set d.total = d.quantity * p.price_exclvat;
```

None of these will work (i.e. you'll again get `too_many_rows` if there are more than a single row in the `product` table whose `npro` matches `detail_order`'s `npro`.

What to do then? It depends on you; we don't have your tables and we don't know what the requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is something like this:

```
update detail_order d
  set total = quantity *
              (select price_exclvat from product where npro = d.npro)
;
```

`quantity` is the quantity from the same row you are updating. There is no reason to reference `detail_order` to retrieve the quantity *for that row*.